# Create a global variable for text size in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing a Flutter App, and one of the steps I need to take is to implement a way for user to increase/decrease the size of the text. For that, I'm thinking about making a slider in the settings page, which is quite straight-forward, but I don't know how to create a global value, change it (so it can't be a constant) and use it everywhere.

Any help is much is much appreciated !

Comment: You can use [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) plugin for this feature. Store a text value in the preferences. Create a variable that contains text size and read this parameter at app start. Next, you should change this variable after user changes its value in preferences.

Answer (score 0):

You can store **persistent data** using [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) or [get_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Hive framework to store the data locally on the device - https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/

First install Hive as a dependency and import it. Initialize Hive using `Hive.initFlutter()` (in the hive_flutter package).

Open a box using `Hive.openBox("boxName")`. Store the box as a variable - `var box = Hive.box("boxName")`.

Add data into the box using `box.put("key", "value")`.

Then you can access the data from anywhere you want by calling `Hive.get("key")`.